# Under what conditions do you use that $\operatorname{Res}{(f(z)/g(z))}=f(z_0)/g'(z_0)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis, this seems to be a really helpful way to avoid having to expand out Laurent series. I am unclear, however, when it is appropriate to use this property.

In specific, I'm worried I CAN'T use this method on the following:

$$\frac{e^z}{z^3 \sin(z)}$$ at the origin. This looks really messy, because using Laurent series, I'll have to divide series. Can I use the property stated above? If not, is there a more efficient way I can approach this problem?

Comment: Only when $z_0$ is a simple pole.

Comment: Should I divide the Laurent series? Can I do that by rewriting it as $$\frac{1}{e^{-z}\sin(z)}$$ And then multiplying through in the denominator?

Comment: Again, $\frac{e^z}{z^3\sin z}$ has an order $4$ pole at $z_0=0$. You need to apply the [limit formula for higher order poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles).

Comment: Isn't it difficult to divide series? I have trouble enough multiplying them; I imagine that's quite a pain. Am I missing a trick? @JessicaK

Comment: @Taylor I started writing up the details for you, but I decided to delete it because it required a much more difficult combination of manipulations than I anticipated. Demosthene's solution is probably the easiest way to do this  since the observation that it's a 4th order pole is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [limit formula for higher order poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles), and the fact that $f(z)=\dfrac{e^z}{z^3\sin z}$ admits an order $4$ pole at $z_0=0$, we get:
$$\mathrm{Res}(f,0)=\dfrac{1}{3!}\lim_{z\to 0}\dfrac{d^3}{dz^3}\left[z^4\dfrac{e^z}{z^3\sin z}\right]=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot 2=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Is there a good way to compute this derivative? I've been working through it for almost an hour now, and I've come up with a nasty expression that is in terms of csc. Is it better to start out by writing $sin(z)$ in terms of e?

Comment: @Taylor Yes, the third derivative is quite nasty indeed... And I get multiple occurrences of $\cot z$ and $\csc z$, which doesn't make life any easier. However, you can Taylor expand them around $0$ and take the limit. And it's not surprising to find that the Taylor series goes like $2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k z^k$.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the series is not so bad really. Rewrite the thing as

$$\frac{1}{z^4}\cdot \frac{e^z}{(\sin z)/z}.$$

We want the coefficient of $z^3$ in the expansion of the second quotient. Now $(\sin z)/z = 1 - (z^2/6 + O(z^4)),$ so its reciprocal is $1+(z^2 + O(z^4)).$ So we are looking at

$$(1+z+z^2/2 + z^3/6 + O(z^4))(1+z^2/6 + O(z^4)).$$

Finding the coefficient of $z^3$ in the above is easy (it's $1/3$), and that is your residue.